# How to properly use SQLAlchemy's '@aggregated' class attribute decorator

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy's @aggregated decorator to define an attribute ('gross_amount)' for a class, Receipt. This `gross_amount` attribute is the sum of the `Item.gross_amount` for all `Item` instances associated with the `Receipt` instance by a foreign id.

I.E., a receipt is made up of items, and I want to define a receipt 'gross_amount' value which is just the total $ of all of the items on the receipt.

I've modeled my code after this document `http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html`

So it looks like this...

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy import orm


class Receipt(Base):
    __tablename__ = "receipts"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = Column(Integer, index = True, primary_key = True, nullable = False)


    @aggregated('itemz', Column(Integer))
    def gross_amount(self):
        return func.sum(Item.gross_amount)

    itemz = orm.relationship(
        'Item',
        backref='receipts'
    )


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"
    id = Column(Integer, index = True, primary_key = True, nullable = False)

    '''
    FE relevant
    '''
    gross_amount = Column(Integer)
    receipt_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("receipts.id"), nullable=False)
```

In my migration, am I supposed to have a column in the `receipts` table for `gross_amount`? 
1) When I DO define this column in the `receipts` table, any `Receipt.gross_amount` for any instance just points to the gross_amount values defined in the `receipts` table.
2) When I DO NOT define this column in the `receipts` table, I get a SQLAlchemy error whenever I execute a `SELECT` against the database:

`ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column receipts.gross_amount does not exist`

FWIW, my `SQLAlchemy` package is the latest distributed thru PIP...

```
SQLAlchemy==1.1.11
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.32.14
```

And my local db on which I'm running this for now is `PostgreSQL 9.6.2`

What am I doing wrong here? Any patient help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to add the column to table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE receipts (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    gross_amount INTEGER,  -- <<< See, it's here :) 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO receipts VALUES(1,7);
INSERT INTO receipts VALUES(2,7);
CREATE TABLE items (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    gross_amount INTEGER, 
    receipt_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(receipt_id) REFERENCES receipts (id)
);
```

Tested with this self-contained snippet:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine, orm
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_utils import aggregated

Base = declarative_base()

class Receipt(Base):
    __tablename__ = "receipts"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = Column(Integer, index = True, primary_key = True, nullable = False)

    @aggregated('itemz', Column(Integer))
    def gross_amount(self):
        return func.sum(Item.gross_amount)

    itemz = orm.relationship('Item', backref='receipts')

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"
    id = Column(Integer, index = True, primary_key = True, nullable = False)   
    gross_amount = Column(Integer)
    receipt_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("receipts.id"), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.gross_amount=amount

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///xxx.db', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

receipt = Receipt()
receipt.itemz.append(Item(5))
receipt.itemz.append(Item(2))

session.add(receipt)
session.commit()

print (receipt.gross_amount)
```

Of course, there's also another approach called `hybrid_property`, which basically allows you to do both orm- and database level queries without adding extra column do your database:

```
@hybrid_property
def gross_sum(self):
    return sum(i.gross_amount for i in self.itemz)

@gross_sum.expression
def gross_sum(cls):
    return select([func.sum(Item.gross_amount)]).\
            where(Item.receipt_id==cls.id).\
            label('gross_sum')
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're getting this error is because the new column you're adding (`gross_amount`) has not been created in the `receipts` table in the database.

Meaning, your current database table only has one created column (`id`). For the aggregated column to work, it needs to contain an additional column called `gross_amount`.

This additional column has to allow `null` values.

One way to go about doing that is through SQL directly in PostgreSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE receipts ADD gross_amount int;
```

Alternatively, if there's no data yet, you can drop and recreate the table via SQLAlchemy. It should create this extra column automatically.

I'm not sure what you mean by the last part:

> When I DO define this column in the receipts table, any 
>       Receipt.gross_amount for any instance just points to the gross_amount 
>       values defined in the receipts table.

That's where it's supposed to point. I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean that it doesn't contain any values, even though there are values for this receipt's items in `Item`? If so, I would double check that this is the case (and per [their examples here](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html), refresh the database session before seeing the results).